# Can't enable client push in Parse (Service Unavailable)

Tags: parse-platform, client, push

Not sure if this is a bug in Parse. But In Push Notification Settings, I'm unable to set "Client push enabled" to "Yes". I get a warning "Service Unavailable". After the warning goes away the setting shows "Yes", but once the page is refreshed it goes back to "No". Anyone else run into this issue, and were you able to fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I have one app that allowed me to enable it, but another will not.

Answer (score 1):

try rename app on parse, e.g. I'm has app name with #-symbol and was been same problem. After renaming all works fine.